# With C sockets, what determines the appearance of a socket's port?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

When I create a socket, and bind it to a port, it will tell me that the socket is listening on the assigned port. For example,

- Create socket.
- Bind to port 7006

However, when I connect to another location, the port number appears to change from the *outside* only. As in, everything works as it should, it just *looks* like the port is different, and I want to know why.

A server program that took a connection from this socket, bound to 7006, said the address was

```
localhost:42566
```

A SOCK_DGRAM socket I made and bound to port 7008 read this address from recvfrom

```
localhost:a3fs-fileserver
```

I figure the a3fs-fileserver is just interpreted that way because it happened to have the port typically associated with a3fs-fileserver and getnameinfo tries to get and english service name when possible.

But why does it look different outside my program than inside? Note: This behavior works the same way between machines as well, I just happened to be testing on one for convenience.

Comment: Connecting to a port has two sockets, the one locally (your client) which is assigned by the OS and the one remotely (the server) that is assigned by the server.  Those are the 2 values that you are seeing.

Comment: Why does what look different from what? You seem to be comparing TCP to UDP, local ports to remote ports, etc. Your question is unclear.

Comment: First check that you are not mixing up local ports with remote ports - there's a source port and a remot port involved in a TCP connection or a UDP datagram. If that's not it, draw us a network map of what you're doing. Where's outside ? Where's your client, and server, and what's in between them ? You might be seeing a [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) gateway that's replacing the port numbers in all your packlets.

Comment: "read this address from recvfrom" <- recvfrom returns the source address (IP & port) of the remote user (in parameter 5).  From that I'd agree that you're looking at the remote port.

Comment: Is there a way to see what the port is on the machine that sent the data, or initiated the connection?

Comment: No, and why would you care?